# Python !pip compile to exe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I hi guys, i wrote a script in Jupyter Notebook and exported it as py, but when compiling with auto-py-to-exe i always get an error.
!pip install selenium can't compiled.
what else can I use instead of pip
(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14ut10NIVRgUglP1WLnTxYhTory_VHEyI?usp=sharing

Comment: Post it in the question itself, not in a comment, since they are prone to deletion. Don't post images of code or errors either. Click the "edit" link under your question to edit it and include info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` is special jupyter "magic". It is not valid python and therefore won't work in a python script. The following will, though:

```
import os
os.system("pip install selenium")
```